# mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet Of Code with Mosh's Ultimate Django Series

Tags: python, django, mysql-connector

If you had been following
[The Ultimate Django Series](https://codewithmosh.com/p/the-ultimate-django-series)  by **code with mosh** and you got to the video :

**4.Setting Up the Database** -> **9- Using MySQL in Django**

and you get the following error in the console on windows :

> mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.qualitestgroup.com/insights/technical-hub/how-to-add-mysql-to-the-path-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add the path of mysql to the system variables, to do that follow this video :

[YOUTUBE GUIDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_b3bgMhzxYY)

**Then restart VSCode !**

Comment: Please do not answer by simply providing a link to a youtube video.